# How to scrape the number in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I want to scrape the number 22.88 from "Apple PE Ratio:22.88 for April 30, 2020" from the following link:

https://ycharts.com/companies/AAPL/pe_ratio

but, because this is the second time I ask a similar question can someone explain to me in brief how created the code?

Comment: There are a lot of good tutorials to help you learn how to download and extract (scrape) data with various R packages like `rvest`. Here is one: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/r-web-scraping-rvest

Comment: Thank you. Exactly I needed a good tutorial because I found many not worthy. Thanks again. I hope someone answers me as well for scraping the number.

Comment: I think you're supposed to sign-up to get access to the export function for the data. Scraping it will possibly see you blocked from accessing the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using rvest and stringr (for the string extraction):

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

url <- 'https://ycharts.com/companies/AAPL/pe_ratio'
webpage <- url %>% read_html()

PEvalue<- webpage %>% html_nodes('span[id="pgNameVal"]') %>% 
                         html_text() 

answer <- str_extract(PEvalue, "(^[0-9.]+)")
```

Or extract with this: `gsub("(^[0-9.]+).*", "\\1", PEvalue)` to avoid loading the stringr package.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty solution in base R.

```
HTML = readLines("https://ycharts.com/companies/AAPL/pe_ratio")
Tag = grep("<span[^<>]*pgNameVal[^<>]*>.*?</span>", HTML)
as.numeric(sub(".*?(\\d+\\.\\d+).*", "\\1", Tag))
22.88
```